# moving object between arrays on different view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have two `view controllers` in a `tab bar controller` each with their own `mutable array` and `tableview`. When I press a row/cell on the first view controller, I want to pass the object that the cell is holding to the second view controller and then delete it from the first view controller.

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            Candy *item = [[Candy alloc]init];
            item = [array1 objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
            SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
            [second.array2 addObject:item];

            [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

and this is what I have in `viewDidLoad` for the second controller (receiving controller):

```
[super viewDidLoad];

 self.tableView.delegate = self;
 self.tableView.dataSource = self;

 self.array2 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
item = [array1 objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
//Do not init a new SecondViewController here, just to get the second VC
UINavigationController *secondNav = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
SecondViewController *second = [[secondNav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[second.array2 addObject:item];
[second.tableView reloadData]; //you should reloadData to see data at VC2, if you don't do this later. 

[array1 removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

BTW, the init method will call initWithNibName for UIViewControler

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, both view controllers r embedded in their own navigation bars because there are separate stacks I use with multiple push segues. I get an error when I run your code for `nsinvalidargumentexception` `-[UINavigationController seatedList]:unrecognized selector

Comment: @snapfish I have edited my answer, and get the UINavigationController first, then to get second viewController in it.

Comment: yes, i just figured it out myself as well. The error is now corrected but the object is still not passed to the secondviewcontroller. Also, the secondviewcontroller's original data now no longer shows.

Comment: the code here is only add a object to array2, why clean the array2 original data? do you do other things to array2 later?

Comment: hmm this is weird. everyhitng works PERFECTLY if when i run the simulator, i go to secondviewcontroller first and then go back to firstviewcontroller to pass the object. However when the screen simulator starts up, we start on the firstviewcontroller and anything we pass is not see. I hope this made sense.

Comment: Do you solve the problem? I think the problem maybe the init of array2, you should do this in init method of second VC.

Comment: I dont see a specific `init` method in second VC. I tried to do it in initWithNibName but that didnt work. Where am i calling this init method for VC2? in VC1 or VC2?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48638/discussion-between-simalone-and-snapfish)

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

First, you're allocating an object and never using it (it's not a bug, but you can correct it). Change this

```
Candy *item = [[Candy alloc]init];
item = [array1 objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
```

for this:

```
Candy *item = [array1 objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
```

Second: Move this line to your `init` method, otherwise it won't work, because by the time you call `[second.array2 addObject:item];` the array hasn't been initalized, and basically you're sending the message to `nil`.

```
self.array2 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: i made both changes (initialized the second array in initWithNibName) and still doesnt work

Comment: `initWithNibName` won't work because you're initializing your `SecondViewController` with `init`, you probably want to initialize it with `initWithNibName`

Comment: ^im sorry but that was a little confusing. Im pretty new at this. Do you mean I should NOT use `init` and switch to using `initWithNibName`? So keep the `array` creation in the `initWithNibName` of the second view controller and actually init the second view controller in the first view controller with `initWithNibName`?

Comment: Exactly! (I'm assuming your second view controller has a xib file from Interface Builder).

Comment: Where do i find the parameters values for `nibNameOrNil` and `nibBundleOrNil`? I only started on xcode5 and the tutorials I use dont really deal with nib stuff.

Comment: `nibNameOrNil` is the name of your xib file form Interface Builder (without extension). `nibBundleOrNil` should be `nil`.

Comment: Im looking at the inspector selection bar but cant seem to find it in storyboard. Is it the title  for the view controller under attributes inspector? It still doesnt work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48632/discussion-between-merlevede-and-snapfish)